# Trying to append modified lists within a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, list, append

So I'm trying to add a new list to a 2d array inside a for loop, by taking the last letter of the list and putting it to the start, and adding this new list to the 2d array.

But although the new lists work, when I append to the 2d array, it just appends the normal alphabet, not my new one.

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

```
def tabulaRecta():
    import string
    alpha = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
    l2d = []
    l2d.append(alpha)
    for i in range(26):
        temp = alpha[len(alpha)-1]
        alpha.pop()
        alpha.insert(0,temp)
        l2d.append(alpha)
    print(l2d)

tabulaRecta()
```

The program is supposed to output something like this, but all of these within a list:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
['Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y']
['Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X']
['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W']
['W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V']
['V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U']
['U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T']
['T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S']
['S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R']
['R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q']
['Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P']
['P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O']
['O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N']
['N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M']
['M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L']
['L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K']
['K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']
['J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I']
['I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
['H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
['G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
['F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
['D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C']
['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B']
['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A']
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

instead it prints this 26 times in a list:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
```

Comment: Can you put a sample output that you need?

Comment: This question badly needs example input, wrong output and desired output.

Comment: i added them sorry im new here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of saying print(...) you can append it to a list and print it when the loop is finished

```
s = list(string.ascii_uppercase)

>>> for i in range(len(s),-1,-1):
...     print(s[i:]+s[:i])

['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
['Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y']
['Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X']
['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W']
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

A 2d array is an array of pointers to arrays, and in your code each one points to the *same list*, that you are modifying 26 times eventually coming back to the original one.

You have to make a copy of the list each time you modify it.
For example, add a `alpha = list(alpha)` at the beginning of the for loop:

```
def tabulaRecta():
        import string
        alpha = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
        l2d = []
        l2d.append(alpha)
        for i in range(26):
            alpha = list(alpha)
            temp = alpha[len(alpha) - 1]
            alpha.pop()
            alpha.insert(0, temp)
            l2d.append(alpha)
        print(l2d)


tabulaRecta()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just do this:

```
import string

def tabula_rect():
    alpha = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
    l2d = []
    l2d.append(alpha)
    for i in range(len(alpha)):
        temp = alpha[len(alpha)-1]
        alpha = alpha[:-1]
        alpha.insert(0, temp)
        l2d.append(alpha)
    return l2d
```